# Makefile including SDL

Tags: c, macos, makefile, path, sdl

I have recently changed distribution (linux to mac).
Since I have a problem with my Makefile for a project.

```
Fatal error: <SDL/SDL.h> file not found
```

When I write the paths of the SDL in absolute directly in my .h it works.
But with the Makefile no, I do not understand why.

```
GRAPH_FLAGS + = -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lncurses -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image

$(GRAPH_NAME):  $(GRAPH_OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $(GRAPH_NAME) $(GRAPH_OBJS) $(GRAPH_FLAGS)
```

Comment: Looks like you added `-I/usr/local/include` while *linking*, but it's required when *compiling*.

Comment: I just tried a cc test.c -I/usr/lib/include and it works for test.c: #include <SDL2/SDL.h> int main() {return 0;}

Answer (score 0):

Use `pkg-config` to get the correct include path:

`` GRAPH_FLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags sdl2` `pkg-config --libs sdl2` -lncurses ... ``

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I found the solution.
It's all stupid, my makefile does not understand the `GRAPH_FLAGS`.
I have changed by the basic `CFLAGS`, I don't know if it comes from the version of my Make but it remains very mystical.
I managed to arrange my makefile because it compiles several programs.
I also went to the SDL2 as it was advised.